# Oracle SQL - Can't Create Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I'm having an issue in sqlplus where I can't execute a script to create a stored procedure. When I try to run the script, I get the following error:

> PLS-000103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
>       begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior external language

I've considered that this might be a simple case of not running the script correctly—when I log into sqlplus, I just enter the following:

```
@ASSIGN_PILOT.sql
```

Is there any reason it shouldn't be running? Is there a different way one is supposed to call scripts for creating stored procedures, or something like that? My script is as follows. I know there are probably a lot of errors in it, but I'll be happy to address them once I can start running this thing.

```
create or replace procedure ASSIGN_PILOT (param_flno int, param_distance int, param_origin char) as

--get all pilot/aircraft combos that can make the trip (call it pilots)
CREATE TABLE pilots
AS
SELECT e.eid, ename, a.aid, cruisingrange
FROM employees1 e
INNER JOIN certified1 c
ON e.eid=c.eid
INNER JOIN aircraft a
ON c.aid=a.aid
ORDER BY cruisingrange ASC;

DECLARE
    CURSOR pl_cur IS
        SELECT * FROM pilots
        ORDER BY cruisingrange ASC;

    pl_row pilots%ROWTYPE;
    is_assigned number;

BEGIN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hi from SP assign_pilot, param_flno = '||param_flno);

    --loop cursor through pilots
    FOR pl_row IN pl_cur LOOP
        --see if the range is long enough
        IF (pl_row.cruisingrange >= param_distance) THEN
            --see if pilot is available (not present in flight_assignments)
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            INTO is_assigned
            FROM flight_assignments FA
            WHERE FA.eid = pl_row.eid;

            --if pilot is available
            IF(is_assigned = 0) THEN
                --add fight to flight_assignments;
                INSERT INTO flight_assignments(flno, aid, eid)
                VALUES(param_flno, pl_cur.aid, pl_cur.eid);
                END;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    --if we reach this point, no one is available.
    --add flight to delayed_flights;
    INSERT INTO delayed_flights
    VALUES(param_flno);
END;
/
show errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't create tables in stored procedures, so that's that!

Answer (score 0):

Creation of a table is possible using a stored procedure with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
However, the DBA has to provide explicit `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO <user>`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tobedeleted
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TEST123 AS SELECT * FROM emp ';
...
...
...
END;
```